# django form clean_<fieldname> method

Tags: django

I looked through similar answers but was surprised there was nothing in that list addressing such a basic question.

My Django form is as follows:

```
class JobApplicationForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    documents = forms.FileField(label="Documents", widget=DocumentUploadWidget)

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()

    def clean_documents(self):
        print ("clean_documents")
        return self.cleaned_data['clean_documents']
```

I can't find how to get clean_documents() to be called.  The documentation says to use the form.is_valid() method but that doesn't work for me.  Here is my sample Django shell session:

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Feb 23 2021, 13:22:40) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from home.forms import JobApplicationForm
>>> f = JobApplicationForm({'message':'sdfsfsdfs'})
>>> f.is_bound
True
>>> f.is_valid()
False
>>> f.errors
{'documents': ['This field is required.']}
>>>
```

At no stage did I see the result of the print statement in the clean_documents() method.  What else needs to happen to see it?

Answer (score 1):

If your form has uploaded files, you need to pass them as the second parameter to your form constructor. Since you didn't, the form cannot find the `documents` field, so it doesn't call `clean_documents()`.

Normally, you'd load the form from a request in your view function like this:

```python
def some_view(request):
    form = JobApplicationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

This example uses `SimpleUploadedFile` instead of a request, so you can run it in your Python shell:

```python
from home.forms import JobApplicationForm
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
f = JobApplicationForm(
        {'message': 'blah'},
        {'documents': SimpleUploadedFile('test.txt', b'contents')})
f.is_valid()
```

The last line prints out `clean_documents`.